# Are there specialized/unique types of pain receptors in the testicles?

Tags: pain, testicles, nociceptor

The sensation of being hit in the testicles seems to be a different kind of pain (in my experience, and in talking to others). I am wondering if this has anything to do with specialized or unique types of nerves inside the testicles. When I look this up on the Internet, everything just says that there is a large concentration of nerves in the testicles, and that is what makes them so sensitive. But, I can't find anything saying if the types of nerves are different (i.e. a type nociceptor only found in the testicles). I find articles talking about different types of nociceptors, such as on the skin, muscles, bones, etc, but nothing mentions the testicles specifically.

Comment: There's no need to postulate special pain receptors. The testicles are basically internal organs that happen to reside outside the main body, which makes them vulnerable to trauma. I'm pretty sure that if your kidneys or any internal organs were similarly positioned and they got hit by something, the pain would be very similar and equally severe.

Comment: Also, where is the prior research? As you should know, it's required here.

Comment: @CareyGregory I mentioned that I didn't find anything specifically talking about the composition of nerves in the testicles, just that there are a plethora nerves in the testicles. The reason I didn't link to any of those articles, is because I believe those articles are impossible to NOT find while researching this. I am confident anyone that does a Google Search on this matter will find those articles mentioning the abundance of nerves immediately. Had I found something mentioning the composition of nerves in the testicles, that would have been relevant and I would have used it.

Comment: I would think that if the testicles had unique nerve endings, it would be very hard not to find a mention of that in articles discussing innervation of the testicles. Any textbook description of nerves in the testicles would certainly mention it. Any list of types of nerve endings would also mention it.